# Github actions - /bin/sh: 1: jest: not found

Tags: github, yarnpkg, github-actions

Using Github actions to publish npm package, It works and runs jest test cases without errors. So I decided to add yarn cache to optimize build time and the cache process works, but jest fails with below error.

```
$ jest --config=jest.config.js
/bin/sh: 1: jest: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 127.
```

Here is my yml

```
name: NPM Publish
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x

      - name: Get yarn cache directory
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

      - uses: actions/cache@v1
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Test cases
        run: yarn run pdn:test
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I suspect the issue is restoring the cached directory does not add back jest to $path, so it either needs to be added manually or called directly through its ./node_modules path

Answer (score 2):

Your pipeline caches only yarn's cache, not node_modules. Jest binary is supposed to be in node_modules, so it (along with other deps) doesn't get restored from cache. This is according to `actions/cache` guidelines, which suggests caching yarn cache and then doing `yarn install`.

`actions/setup-node` can already handle yarn caching, no need to roll your own logic for that.

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
          cache: yarn

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - run: yarn run test
```

If you really want to cache node_modules instead of yarn's cache, then cache the directory manually

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 12.x

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node_modules-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - run: yarn run test
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and I referred a bit of how others were doing. Maybe give this a shot

```yaml
- name: Cache dependencies
  uses: actions/cache@v1
  id: yarn-cache
  with:
    path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
- name: Install Dependencies (from network)
  if: steps.cache-deps.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  run: |
    yarn policies set-version
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-optional
- name: Install Dependencies (from cache)
  if: steps.cache-deps.outputs.cache-hit == 'true'
  run: |
    yarn policies set-version
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-optional --offline
```

Comment: This solves the problem of the command not being found, but significantly negates the benefit of caching, time-wise. Both the online and offline steps take similar amounts of time to run due to building fresh packages.